# `EnumDisplaySettings` repeating same Resolution Multiple Times

Tags: winapi, qt, gdi

Here goes my code

```
DEVMODE dm;
int index = 0;
while(0 != EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, index++, &dm)){
    qDebug() << index-1 << dm.dmPelsWidth << dm.dmPelsHeight;
    Resolution* resolution = new Resolution(dm.dmPelsWidth, dm.dmPelsHeight);
}
```

Outputs

```
0 320 200 
1 320 200 
2 320 200 
3 320 240 
4 320 240 
5 320 240 
6 400 300 
7 400 300 
8 400 300 
9 512 384 
10 512 384 
11 512 384 
12 640 400 
13 640 400 
14 640 400 
15 640 480 
.....
25 640 480 
26 640 480 
27 800 600 
.....
41 800 600 
42 1024 768 
50 1024 768 
51 1152 864 
....
62 1152 864 
63 1280 600
```

I get only one thing in return that is `320x200` not even the `1600x900` which is my current Resolution.

Answer (score 2):

`EnumDisplaySettings` gives you every possible combination of screen parameters.

The trick is knowing which fields of the `DEVMODE` structure to pay attention to.

These significant fields are:

- dmDisplayFixedOutput
- dmDisplayFrequency
- dmPelsWidth
- dmPelsHeight
- dmBitsPerPel

For example, here are the first 14 legitimate settings for my monitor:

```
    dmPelsWidth dmPelsHeight  dmBitsPerPixel  dmDisplayFrequence  dmDisplayFixedOutput         
    640           480            8              59                  Default 
    640           480            8              59                 Stretch 
    640           480            8              59                  Center 
    640           480            8              60                 Default 
    640           480            8              60                 Stretch 
    640           480            8              60                  Center 
    640           480            8              75                 Default 
    640           480            16             59                 Default 
    640           480            16             59                 Stretch 
    640           480            16             59                  Center 
    640           480            16             60                 Default 
    640           480            16             60                 Stretch 
    640           480            16             60                  Center 
    640           480            16             75                 Default 
    (... etc ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it in a loop. My feeling is that replacing the `if` with a `while` will instantly solve this.

Comment: But Its giving a List of 364 Resolutions. which is too much and Its repeating the same resolution multiple Times. I am updating My Question. Please Check it.